# difference between li.parent and ul

Tags: css, html-lists, parent

Um troubling to understand with this parent keyword.
Are li.parent and ul same ?
if it is,can anyone tell me whats this meaning about.thanks
(nav and sidebar are classes).

```
.sidebar ul.nav .active > a:focus, .sidebar ul.nav li.parent a.active:focus {
color: #fff;
background-color: #2e2e2e;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a class name that's all...it has no special CSS powers or semantic value.

> Are li.parent and ul same ?

No....a `ul` is a an element *type*...`li.parent` is just a list item with a class of "parent".

What that means will depend on how it is used.

It's *likely* to mean that the specific `li` has a sub-menu but without the relevant HTML it's hard to confirm.

Comment: ah..I just checked that html and,you right.there has that "parent" class.I forget to check that html file,so I thought it s some kinda define keyword or something.. thank you very much.

Comment: "Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". "
R U Kidding me.I cant even say "thank you" to a person who made my day.um sure there is a person behind every code here,they r human.likes to hear compliments like everybody does .if you don't know that you shouldn't be coding for humans.(this for that lame rule maker)